# Pentaho Report Designer Database connection with variable on preview

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I set the db credentials in kettle.properties,
i set the variables with credentials in data source successfully
[image]
but when i click preview it gives me this error, it seems that it can't recognize the variable
[image]
This is how I declared the variables in kettle.properties
[image]
How can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

1.I just use mysql instance, your kettle.properties is right.
[image]
2.Have you try to ping url of your db and login in your centos or ubuntu?
[image]

3.I think the most important problem is network and authority of db in whitelist.
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

4.My kettle
[image]

Comment: do you mean try turning off the firewall of the oracle db?

Comment: Have you try to ping ip of Oracle?

Comment: And close you firewall of you PC, just for a second

Comment: If it dosen't work, I will find another way, don't worry, i think is't not hard

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said but it doesn't work. If I set the data in clear text, without using the variables, I can run the preview. But I must use variables

Comment: Ok, I will find another way tomorrow. Could you post some picture with variables?

Comment: Ok thank you, I edited the post by inserting the declaration of the variables in the kettle.properties

Comment: I will try tonight, give me some time.

Comment: Yes I'll wait, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. There are lots of works to do.

Comment: Hi, I see you use Spoon, is it the same as report designer?

Comment: Right, it's same. Why don't try use mysql, because it's a little diffcult. In order to find you problem.

Comment: I show you in the answer. Just leave some word if you have any question, we can discuss.